# Getting the Object Calling a Method

Tags: java, class, object, methods, method-call

In java, how can you get the object calling a method, within the method it is calling, if the method is in another class? I have looked all over the internet and no solution. Could someone please help?

Comment: There isn't necessarily an object calling a method. What if you called the method from a `static` method or `static` initializer?

Comment: Why do you need this information?

Comment: Create Singleton class for that!

Comment: A really awful way to get some information about the call stack is to generate a fake Exception and look at it's dump, but don't think that solves this question.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to pass `this` to the method,

```
static void someMethod(Object o) {
  System.out.println(o);
}
void testIt() {
  someMethod(this); // <-- pass the current instance to the method.
}
```

Comment: To access the instance of the calling class he would need to have an instance already created by the second class in order to invoke the calling classes method. No? If so, it would be a different instance. The only way I see is for the calling class to store a static reference of itself, which is troublesome but would allow him to invoke a static method to obtain the desired instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

The last element of this array will be the recent object you have used. But it should better to use an extra argument as above answer said and pass `this` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance that you need to receive an instance of the first class then you can prepare the second class to receive it as follows.

```
public class class1 {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    new class1();

 }

 public class1()
 {
    send();
 }

 private void send()
 {
   new class2().receiveClass(this);// creates an instance of class 2 and sends a reference of class1 (this)
 }

 public void print()
 {
    System.out.println("class1.print()");
 }
}
```

To receive in the second class.

```
public class class2 {

 private class1 c1;

 public void receiveClass(class1 c)
 {
    c1=c;
    c1.print(); //accessing the print method of class1, the same instance that references this object.
 }

}
```

This will also work if the solutions given above do not work for you.